# Very high disk IO on Mongodb Config servers

Tags: linux, debian, mongodb

Perhaps someone could tell me if this is expected or not (It doesn't seem normal to me)...  On all 3 of my config servers I am seeing consistent high disk IO, even when the sharded-cluster has extremely low activity.   According to iotop the mongodb process is causing disk writes fluctuating between about 500KB/s and 1000KB/s (there are virtually no reads).   I know the log files are constantly being updated with sync messages (and would love to not have these logged), but looking at tail these are of the frequency of about 1 line per second on average, so I don't believe that this can account for the IO stats I see.

It was my understanding that config servers didn't really need to do that much, and mainly needed to keep track of how data is sharded (and since there are low db writes at the moment, there's not much of this going on).  I'm running on Debian 6 64bit.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you running on?  Both the performance and logging related issues were fixed in 2.4.5 as part of the fix for [SERVER-5442](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5442).

Hence, if you are running an earlier build you should upgrade and use `--quiet` to verify the fix as well as the logging change.  If you are running 2.4.5 or newer, then you should restart the processes one by one, verify that the issue persists and then, if so, open a new bug to investigate (usually involves running a higher log level for a while to gather information).

Note: Per the follow up in the comments below, the key here is to upgrade all **clients** to 2.4.5+, not just the config servers.  This is because the write concern (which is the performance fix from SERVER-5442) is controlled client-side, not on the server.  Clients to the config servers are generally the `mongos` and (primary) `mongod` processes, hence it is recommended to upgrade all components to see the impact of the fixes.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running 2.4.5, and also have quiet=true in the configuration file (I'm assuming that is the same as the --quiet flag).  I've restarted all of the processes in my cluster to no avail.  I've just noticed that some mongos processes on the app servers (not part of the mongodb cluster) are running 2.4.3 though - perhaps this is the issue...

Comment: Yes, the relevant change is actually (somewhat counter-intuitively) on the client side (the mongos) which is what decides how the writes are done on the config servers (see: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/cee9135e0f478bc60cbe599a6822c11fcbdb9dd0), hence you have to make sure all the mongos processes are on 2.4.5+ to resolve the issues.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  So after upgrading those mongos clients the disk activity on the config servers has fallen by about 50%. It still seems a little on the high side to me, but a vast improvement!  Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that the mongod's (the primaries) also write to the config servers, though less often, so worth looking at upgrading those to 2.4.5+ also.  There are a couple of other things to check too - have a look at the config.changelog collection to get an idea of activity on your cluster - it's a 10MB capped collection that will show you the activity - in particular migrates will cause writes from the primaries.

Comment: Every member of each shard replica set is 2.4.5. I don't think there's much in the way of migrates happening either, as writes are very low on the cluster at the moment.  I haven't looked the config.changelog before though, so will check this out. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just one more question :) - Since the mongos clients decide the activity on the config server, is it neccesary to add quiet=true to the mongos configs if I want to reduce logging on the config servers?

Comment: No, the change is actually in the shared connection code for any mongod/mongos (as a client) making a connection to the config server (it's a special type of connection), so no need to run the mongos with quiet.